# Trying to find a Model for multiclass classification problem where you want two classes close together but far away from a third?

Tags: classification, statistics, feature-selection, machine-learning-model, multiclass-classification

So I've got this problem where I want to find out where two classes are more a like ( features wise) than a third. So for example if I have three classes {A,B,C} I want to find out where class A and B are close together but as far away as possible from class C and find the features that contribute to this the most.

Another example if I've got a green apple (class A), a pear (class B) and a red apple (class C) I want the model to give me the feature green (since that is where the green apple and pear look most alike and look nothing at all like the red apple).

I've no clue if there is an existing model which can do this, so if anybody knows one, or knows a method which with a little tweaking could do this I would be really happy to hear.

Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT:

I tried separating classes with a sPLS-DA, which gave me the following separation of classes.

[image]

Which is a nice first run, but I really want to reduce the separation of classes A and B and increase the separation of A and C.

Comment: You can use a similarity matrix, like a recommender system and then write a function to recognize the sameness and differences based on some spread of similarity dissimilarity that you choose.

Comment: But than doesn’t the similarity matrix show a greater similarity between the two appels, since the look much more alike, which in this case is not the desired behavior

Comment: It depends on what data fields you enter and how you compute it. If you have a color column and a fruit type column and a weight column. Then each attribute should be used in the matrix. You need to decide how to constrain and empower the matrix by the variables you choose. But Type might be a similarity you wanted in there, or it may not.

Comment: The thing is that the example is a simplification of the real dataset (more than 20.000 features), so the model needs to tell me which features are important for the separation of classes. I can not define this by hand. 

I think the first part of the solution makes sense. I need to compare my subjects by a similarity measure , but then I want to find out which features contributed to this the most.

Comment: A solution I was thinking of, but don't know if it is possible was to perform some sort of supervised PCA where I classify A and B as the same class (say AB) and try to separate them as best as possible from class C while try to reduce the in sample error or spread of the AB group. Than the loadings would tell me which features contribute to this particular separation the most. But I can't seem to find such a model.

Comment: So, if you do similarity before feature selection it will become conflicted down the road. You can try doing some clustering to create natural clusters, and use feature importance to get a sense of the most contributing variables